# Unwanted row deletion in Hibernate, when mapping many-to-one

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping in my hibernate application. When I delete a row from this Booking table, the correspondent rows in the User and item tables are deleted. I use delete method of hibernate Session. I tried cascade="all" and "none". But neither of them worked.

I have some Users and some items. Each user can have 0..* rows and each item can have0..* rows in the Booking table!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="my.hibernate.operations.Booking" table="testBooking" catalog="efeu">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="userID" column="user_id"
            not-null="true" class="my.hibernate.actors.User" />
        <many-to-one name="itemID" column="item_id" 
            not-null="true" class="my.hibernate.items.Item" />

        <property name="startDate" type="java.sql.Date" not-null="true">
            <column name="start_date" length="10" />
        </property>

        <property name="endDate" type="java.sql.Date">
            <column name="end_date" length="10" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It provieds me with the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`efeu`.`testbooking`, CONSTRAINT `FKEC7473671463A66C` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `testuser` (`id`))
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    $Proxy8.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3337)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:280)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    my.hibernate.items.ItemDAO.save(ItemDAO.java:35)
    actions.subscriber.BookItem.cancellBooking(BookItem.java:118)
    actions.subscriber.BookItem.execute(BookItem.java:101)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:52)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`efeu`.`testbooking`, CONSTRAINT `FKEC7473671463A66C` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `testuser` (`id`))
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1169)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:693)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1404)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1318)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1303)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    $Proxy8.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3337)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:280)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    my.hibernate.items.ItemDAO.save(ItemDAO.java:35)
    actions.subscriber.BookItem.cancellBooking(BookItem.java:118)
    actions.subscriber.BookItem.execute(BookItem.java:101)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:52)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
```

Anyway, due to requests I copy the structure of all tables, however I know it is not needed! Attention! These tables have been made automatically by Hibernate!

```
CREATE TABLE `testuser` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forename` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userlevel` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `payable` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `testbooking` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKEC747367A12BE486` (`item_id`),
  KEY `FKEC7473671463A66C` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKEC7473671463A66C` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `testuser`
(`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKEC747367A12BE486` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `testitem`
(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `testitem` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trackNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pages_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edition` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, `Booking` is a junction entity between `User` entity and `Item` entity. Judging by the entity names, `User` is the owner of the relationship.

In this case, the Hibernate mapping for `User` entity should look like this:-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="...User" ...>
        <id name="id" column="user_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <set name="bookings" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="user_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="Booking"/>
        </set>

        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The `User` entity looks something like this:-

```
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private Collection<Booking> bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
    ...

    // assuming if you want to create bi-directional relationship between User and Booking
    public void addBooking(Booking booking) {
        booking.setUser(this);
        bookings.add(booking);
    }

    // getters and setters
    ...
}
```

To remove a booking from the user, instead of deleting it directly from the `Booking` entity, you will want to do it this way:-

- First, you get hold of the user object first, ex: `session.load(User.class, <someUserId>);`
- Find and remove the booking object from `user.getBookings()` collection.
- Update the user object ( `session.saveOrUpdate(user);` ) and the cascade will automatically remove the entry from the `Booking` table.

Comment: I hate this method because it makes me add a column to the book table, containing a collection. It is certainly wrong for my case. In this case I will have to add the set to the item too. It will be not only redundant but prohibits me from searching well in the booking table. My Project is a webapp for a library. User can book and rent an item(book/cd) and I only need to have an extra column for the user to have the number of the items rented and booked by the user. And it is not of interest to have the list of those books in a column.

Comment: Why do you need to add a column to the `Book` table to do just this? Your DDL looks perfectly fine to me. You only need to add the set to `Item` ONLY IF it makes sense to your app. If your app doesn't require you to get a list of bookings by item, then there's no point adding that set to `Item`. Before you hate something, I would advice you to read up on how Hibernate handles parent-child relationship.

Comment: If I don't have to add this column. May you tell me please what I should insert inside the set tag? Should I remove the many-to-one declaration from the Booking class?

Comment: I updated the post above. You don't have to remove the many-to-one in `Booking` if you want to establish a bi-directional relationship between `Booking` and `User`. (ex: You may want to get hold of the user information of the booking... `booking.getUser().getFirstName()` ).

Comment: hmmm! let me try it. I had tried it some days ago but I had failed due to duplicate object exceptions. I can't remember well. Maybe I hadn't designed the equals and hashcode well!